# Push Referral URL when form is submitted GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to push the referral URL to Google Analytics once someone submits the form on my landing page.  Is it possible to do this using Google Tag Manager and also pass a successful form completion?

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: Would that be anything different from the referrer GA tracks by default ?

Comment: GA tracks it by default. You don have to push anything for the referrer. Create some custom reports in GA to see the data

Comment: Sounds like what can be done generally for all sorts of variables!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any reason to pull the referral URL within GTM. Google Analytics (GA) already does this. To view referrer information, simply add a secondary dimension! Here's a screenshot of where to find the secondary dimension option:
[image]

You can use the search box in the secondary dimension dropdown menu to find and apply the `Full Referrer` dimension. Below, I've provided a screenshot showing the `Full Referrer` column that is added:
[image]